# Obtain array from IplImage in JavaCV

Tags: opencv, javacv

I need to convert the code below from C++ to Java. In C++ I use openCV and I need to convert it in Java using JavaCV.

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(argv[0]);
int rows = img->height;
int cols = img->width;

Mat matimg(img);
vector<vector<double> > img_vec(rows, vector<double>(cols));

for (int i=0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j =0; j < cols; j++){
        unsigned char temp;
        temp = ((uchar*) matimg.data + i * matimg.step)[j  * matimg.elemSize() + 1 ];
        img_vec[i][j] = (double) temp;
    }
}
```

I've tried the following conversion to java, but it doesn't work properly. I printed the values of temp and it is 0 all the times and for the same imgage the values of matimg.step and matimg.elemSize() are different in the C++ code and the Java code. 
In c++ I get matimg.step = 2400 and matimg.elemSize() = 3 while in Java i get 3000 and 1.

Here is the code in java:

```
IplImage img = cvLoadImage(argv[0]);
int rows = img.height();
int cols = img.width();

CvMat matimg = img.asCvMat();
double img_vec[][] = new double[rows][cols];
for (int i=0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j =0; j < cols; j++){
         short temp;
         temp = matimg.data_s().get(i * matimg.step() + j  * matimg.elemSize() + 1);
         img_vec[i][j] = (double) temp;
    }
}
```

I don't understand where am I doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated question. Why are you using IplImage*??

In C++ you can do cv::Mat img = cv::imread("file.jpg");

Comment: I need to obtain in java the matrix representation (in img_vec). I have the code in C++ where it works but when I do that in Java it doesn't work. My question was how i obtain the matrix in java not in c++. CvMat in Java is not the same with Map in c++? I couldn't find very much help for javaCV.

Comment: Check if the images you actually feed the two programs are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved my problem using this:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = img.getByteBuffer();
double img_vec[][] = new double[rows][cols];
for (int i=0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j =0; j < cols; j++){
        int ind = i * img.widthStep() + j * img.nChannels() + 1;
        img_vec[i][j] = (buffer.get(ind) & 0xFF);
    }
}
```